# Getopt::Lazy does not print usage message or anything else

Tags: perl, getopt-long

I need some help using perls Getopt::Lazy module. I tried the example from the cpan page:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#
#use warnings;
#use strict;
use Getopt::Lazy
        'help|h' => 'Show this help screen',
        'verbose|v' => 'Show verbose output',
        'output|o=s' => ["[FILE] Send the output to FILE", 'getopt.out'],
        'output-encoding=s' => ['[ENCODING] Specify the output encoding', 'utf8'],
        -summary => 'a simple example usage of Getopt::Lazy',
        -usage => '%c %o file1 [file2 ..]',
        ;
getopt;
print usage and exit 1 unless @ARGV;
```

When I put it in a file and execute it like `./mygetopt.pl -h` , I would expect the help message to be printed, but nothing happens. When I call it without the `-h` argument, I would expect it to print the usage message. Nothing like this happens. Also, when I use strict and warnings, I get messages like

```
Unquoted string "usage" may clash with future reserved word at ./mygetopt.pl line 14.
Bareword "getopt" not allowed while "strict subs" in use at ./mygetopt.pl line 13.
Execution of ./mygetopt.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Example with Getopt::Long + Pod::Usage  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22104215/how-to-get-getoptlong-pod2usage-working

Comment: Another example: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=155288

Comment: More recent, easier to read example:  https://gist.github.com/sirhc/621139

Comment: I opened a new ticket for this: https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=107662

Comment: Looks like the RT ticket did the trick. New version on CPAN with a fixed synopsis.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [SYNOPSIS](https://metacpan.org/pod/Getopt::Lazy#SYNOPSIS) for that module is completely out of step with the actual code. There are no functions called `getopt` or `usage` in the code. They are actually called `GetOptions` and `Getopt::Lazy::show_help` (yes, one is exported, the other is not - who knows why). Rewriting the example like this will work:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use Getopt::Lazy
        'help|h' => 'Show this help screen',
        'verbose|v' => 'Show verbose output',
        'output|o=s' => ["[FILE] Send the output to FILE", 'getopt.out'],
        'output-encoding=s' => ['[ENCODING] Specify the output encoding', 'utf8'],
        -summary => 'a simple example usage of Getopt::Lazy',
        -usage => '%c %o file1 [file2 ..]',
        ;
GetOptions;
Getopt::Lazy::show_help and exit 1 unless @ARGV;
```

But given the quality of the documentation and given that the module was apparently abandoned by its author seven and a half years ago, I wouldn't let it anywhere near any of my projects. You would be far better advised to use one of the solutions suggested by other people in the comments above.